# SSIS Custom Connection Manager not working in Script Component

Tags: c#, ssis, sharepoint-online

I am creating a very simple connection manager for working with our SharePoint online list.  The connection manager is working fine when I access it through a script task.  However when I try to access it through a script component in a data flow I get the following error.

***Object reference not set to an instance of the object.***

I do have the Connection Manager added to the 'Connection Managers' tab of the script component.

I do not think this is due to how I've coded the connection manager since it works with script tasks and is very basic code mostly written by Microsoft.  The code in my script component is also very basic and mostly from the the instructions on Microsoft's site.  I will include the code for the script component as well as the connection manager.

Connection Manager

```
using System;
using System.Security;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;


namespace SharePointConnectionManager
{
    [DtsConnection(
        ConnectionType = "SPOWEB",
        DisplayName = "SharePoint Online Web Connection",
        Description = "Connection Manager for SharePoint Online")]
    public class SharePointConnectionManager : ConnectionManagerBase
    {
        public string SiteUrl { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public SharePointConnectionManager()
        {
            SiteUrl = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            UserName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        }

        public override object AcquireConnection(object txn)
        {
            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(SiteUrl);

            SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
            Password.ToList().ForEach(securePassword.AppendChar);

            ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, securePassword);

            Web web = ctx.Web;
            ctx.Load(web);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            return web;
        }

        public override void ReleaseConnection(object connection)
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                base.ReleaseConnection(connection);
            }
        }

        public override DTSExecResult Validate(IDTSInfoEvents infoEvents)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SiteUrl))
            {
                infoEvents.FireError(0, "SharePoint Connection Manager", "Site URL is mandatory.", string.Empty, 0);
                return DTSExecResult.Failure;
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName))
            {
                infoEvents.FireError(0, "SharePoint Connection Manager", "UserName is mandatory.", string.Empty, 0);
                return DTSExecResult.Failure;
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
            {
                infoEvents.FireError(0, "SharePoint Connection Manager", "Password is mandatory.", string.Empty, 0);
                return DTSExecResult.Failure;
            }
            return DTSExecResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Script Component

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
#endregion

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    IDTSConnectionManager100 connMgr;
    Web spoWeb;

    public override void AcquireConnections(object Transaction)
    {
        connMgr = this.Connections.Connection;
        spoWeb = (Web)connMgr.AcquireConnection(Transaction);
    }

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(spoWeb.ToString());

    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        /*
         * Add your code here
         */
    }

    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.SiteUrl = "I don't know";
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you an Admin?  Are you running from inside VS?  VS doesn't automatically run As Admin. You need to right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  The executable will run As Admin outside VS.

Comment: I was not, however I did restart VS as admin and got the same results.